# How to create a unique_for_field slug in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, slug

Django has a [unique_for_date](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique-for-date) property you can set when adding a SlugField to your model. This causes the slug to be unique only for the Date of the field you specify:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique_for_date='publish')
    publish = models.DateTimeField()
```

What would be the best way to achieve the same kind of functionality for a non-DateTime field like a ForeignKey? Ideally, I want to do something like this:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique_for='category')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

This way I could create the following urls:

```
/example/category-one/slug
/example/category-two/slug
/example/category-two/slug <--Rejected as duplicate
```

**My ideas so far:**

- **Add a unique index for the slug and categoryid to the table.** This requires code outside of Django. And would the built-in admin handle this correctly when the insert/update fails?
- **Override the save for the model and add my own validation, throwing an error if a duplicate exists.** I know this will work but it doesn't seem very DRY.
- **Create a new slug field inheriting from the base and add the unique_for functionality there.** This seems like the best way but I looked through the core's unique_for_date code and it didn't seem very intuitive to extend it.

**Any ideas, suggestions or opinions on the best way to do this?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about [unique_together](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together)?

```
class Example(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField(db_index=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('slug','category'),)
        # or also working since Django 1.0:
        # unique_together = ('slug','category',)
```

This creates an index, but it is not outside of Django ;) <strike>Or did I miss the point?</strike>

Comment: Of course, it's as simple as that. Thanks for the help and updating the answer!